How can I debug what triggers systemd sleep.target?
I have a Linux system based on minimal Ubuntu 22.04 and kernel 6.5.3 that uses systemd as its init.
Shortly after boot, something causes the system to suspend, which is undesirable, as there's no means to wake it.
I suspect it's something to do with a USB-attached touch pad, because swapping for a different model of touch-pad fixes the symptom.  Note that swapping for another of the same model still suspends, so it's not a failed peripheral; also the problem touch pad works find with a different model of motherboard, so it's clearly due to the combination of host and device.  Also, this behaviour didn't occur with a previous installation based on Ubuntu 14.04 with Upstart as init.
I have been able to access the system and run systemctl mask target.sleep; that provides an adequate work-around for the time being.  But I'd like to understand and perhaps eliminate the root cause.  What tools are available to investigate why systemd is attempting to reach the "sleep" target?
I'm hoping there's something I can inspect on the running system (with target.sleep masked) to track down where the desire to sleep originates.  If needed, I can systemctl unmask target.sleep (causing the system to suspend immediately) then inspect logs after powering down and rebooting.  I'm happy to install extra packages or to recompile the kernel with extra options - I just don't know which ones I should be using.

"which is undesirable, as there's no means to wake it" I love the polite understatement in there.

I can't dynamically plug it in without some re-wiring (it shares a connector with the LVDS screen it overlays, and hotplugging is known to cause damage).  But I can plug it into the other kind of motherboard and investigate it there.  What tool should I use to parse its HID descriptor?  There are no physical keys on the touch pad, but it's possible that an unused input to its control IC might be connected to the wrong rail; I'd be able to request a design revision based on that if true.

lsusb -vvv on the vendor:device will list its endpoints and descriptors,which you might compare with the other device. There is usbmon to trace usb transactions, but it is a bit complex. You might try using at boot libhid-detach-device to stop interpreting HID events from your device,and seeing if you are still suspending. I wouldn't give up on a possible hardware problem, e.g. some unconnected floating pin causing an acpi suspend event.

lsusb only gives the USB identifiers (yes, I have those), but not the HID descriptors - I think I'd need the latter to determine if there's a "power" button.  I agree that my suspicion is that there could be an unconnected input - or more likely, a tied input to which is treated as level-sensitive rather than edge-sensitive.  I'll see if I can get the schematics of the touch pad and look for warning signs.

@meuh, I've edited your comments to make a CW answer; if you want to reap the points from it, please copy that content into a new one of your own and I'll delete mine.

That's fine. I hope you'll be able to update it with what you discovered was the problem. I'll delete my comments.


You might look at the /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/ rules for the device and see if it has any keys that generate sleep or suspend.
I've not delved this low in USB HIB devices, but you can get some HID info by reading /sys/kernel/debug/hid/*:<vendor>:<devid>.*/rdesc. I'm not sure where this is documented. You need to mount -t debugfs none_debugs /sys/kernel/debug first. There is also usbhid-dump from usbutils, and hidapitester.
Use evtest to trace what events it is generating, or xinput --test-xi2 --root if using X11.
systemd-analyze might have some info.
Create your own systemd unit with Before=sleep.target and WantedBy=sleep.target, and get it to execute ps or similar.  That might help you narrow down which processes are most active at the time.
You can use systemd-inhibit --what=sleep $some_cmd to block requests to suspend; see logind.conf man page.


(Originally posted in comments by meuh)
